# Code which give me error message but not clearing the error message after entering field

Tags: javascript, html

---

*Code which give me error message but not clearing the error message after entering field :*

```js
var flag = 0;
function otpValidate() {
     otp = oneTimePass.onetimepass.value;
     if(otp == "") {
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "Enter one time password";
         flag = 1;
     } else if(otp.length != 6) { 
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "PIN must be 6 digits";
         flag = 1;
     }
 }  
 function check(form) {
     flag = 0;
     otpValidate();
     if (flag == 1)
         return false;
     else
         return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an empty message in your main function. Then call a `keyup` function to call your main function. try something like:

```
function otpValidate() {
    var otp = oneTimePass.onetimepass.value.trim();
     if(otp == "") {
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "Enter one time password";
         flag = 1;
     } else if(otp.length != 6) { 
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "PIN must be 6 digits";
         flag = 1;
     }
     else { 
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "";
         flag = 0;
     }
 }  

var otp = oneTimePass.onetimepass;
otp.addEventListener("keyup", otpValidate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Optimized way

```
function otpValidate() {
     otp = oneTimePass.onetimepass.value.trim();
     document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "";
     flag = 0;
     if(!otp) {
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "Enter one time password";
         flag = 1;
     } else if(otp.length != 6) { 
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "PIN must be 6 digits";
         flag = 1;
     }
    return flag;
 }  
function check(form) {

     var flag  = otpValidate();
     if (flag == 1)
         return false;
     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var flag = 0;
function otpValidate() {
     otp = oneTimePass.onetimepass.value;
     if(otp == "") {
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "Enter one time password";
         flag = 1;
     } else if(otp.length != 6) { 
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "PIN must be 6 digits";
         flag = 1;
     }
     else { 
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "";
         flag = 0;
     }
 }  
 function check(form) {
     otpValidate();
     if (flag == 1)
         return false;
     else
         return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all fix the codes here

```
function check(form) {
     //flag = 0; This will make no sense to check it

     otpValidate();
     if (flag == 1)
         {
         flag = 0;
         return false;
         }

     else
         return true;
 }
```

And for the problem you are facing

```
function otpValidate() {
     otp = oneTimePass.onetimepass.value;
     if(otp == "") {
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "Enter one time password";
         flag = 1;
     } else if(otp.length != 6) { 
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "PIN must be 6 digits";
         flag = 1;
     }
     else { 
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "";
     }
 }
```